# Using odd and even selectors on child elements pseudo css3

Tags: css

I am looking to using CSS3 pseudo selectors of Odd and Even to select every 2nd image in the HTML. However the images are nested inside P tags. And not every P tag has an image.

For example:

```
<p><img src="/example.jpg" /></p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p><img src="/example.jpg" /></p>
<p><img src="/example.jpg" /></p>
<p>text</p>
<p><img src="/example.jpg" /></p>
```

The placement of  P tags inbetween without images inside is random.

I tried this solution, but it doesn't work as it targets the odd and even of the P tags (not the image)

```
p:nth-child(odd) img{
  border:4px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS unfortunately AFAIK. JQuery would be your solution I feel.

Comment: Not possible to find just with CSS ...

Comment: What about nth-of-type(ood) ?

Comment: You're going to have the same problem either way – `nth-of-type` only applies to elements (not full selectors), and you can't traverse into the `<p>` and then get out of it again (you can't match a sibling of a `<p>` with an image inside of it)

Comment: Most robust solution would be to add a class server-side to whether images (2 alternate classes or 1 image with class and 1 without) or paragraphs (2 alternate classes). Otherwise JS is needed

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with CSS, as far as I am aware. 'Content aware' selectors have been proposed for the CSS specification, but have not been implemented.

The easiest solution would be to use Javascript to target the images in the `<p>` tags. I assume all your `p`'s are in a containing element, such as a div? If so, the following solution is possible, using jQuery:

```
$('div.mycontainer img').each(function(index, element) {
    if (index % 2 != 0) {
        element.addClass('border');
    }
});
```

The logical condition of the if statement targets even elements by using the `modulus` operator. `border` is a class which could contain your special styling rules, like so:

```
.border {
    border:4px solid black;
}
```